# Animating Bootstrap progress bar width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, progress-bar

I want to animate a progress bar's width from 0% to 70% over 2.5 seconds. However, the code below immediately changes the width to 70% after a 2.5 second delay. What am I missing?

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
    width: "70%"
}, 2500);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/

Comment: My friend what browser are you using for testing, I am checking your code in firefox 28, and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is in default Bootstrap transition effect, which animates any update of the `width` property.

If you switch it off with supressing the corresponding style, it will work fine, e.g.:

```
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/1/

Comment: That did it. I just noticed Safari handled the animation fine, but Chrome had an issue with Bootstrap's transition effect. Thanks!

Comment: @user3088077 Yes, most probably Chrome tries to combine both animations and fall into displaying only the CSS transition when the jQuery animation is already internally completed.

Comment: how to use with more than one progress-bar in same page?

Comment: how to make it leniar?

Answer (score 7):

So, it makes more sense to adjust the transition effect via CSS or jQuery.

```
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-transition: width 2.5s ease;
    transition: width 2.5s ease;
}
```

And just change the width value.

```
$(".progress-bar").css('width', '70%');
```

Answer (score 4):

**IT'S very EASY** if uses bootstrap progress bar,

only add attrib aria-valuenow="percent_required%" to div with class "progress-bar" like this:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="57%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="57">
```

Next, on script:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('ready',function(){
    $('.progress .progress-bar').css("width",function() {
      return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
    })
  })
</script>
```

Reload, Go!

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by adding:

```
.progress .progress-bar {
  transition: unset;
}
```

```js
var delay = 500;
$(".progress-bar").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(delay * i).animate({
    width: $(this).attr('aria-valuenow') + '%'
  }, delay);

  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: delay,
    // easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.progress {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
}

.bg-purple {
  background-color: #825CD6 !important;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap 4 Progress Bars</h2>
  <div class="progress border">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">70</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress border">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50</div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress border">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-purple" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">90</div>
  </div>
</div>
```