# jQuery.animate() seems to take duration parameter as a delay

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I'm having the worst trouble in getting my animation works with jQuery. My goal is to animate a **5%** `width` Bootstrap `.progress-bar` to **100%** `width`.

**My code**:

*HTML*

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        Box title
        <span class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-id="2" rel="tooltip" title="Remove">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-2 progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 5%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">Long content here...</div>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.progress-'+id).animate({width: '100%'}, 5000, 'linear');
    });
});
```

*What is expected*: having the `.progress-bar` slowly increase its `width` from 5% to 100%.

*What I'm actually getting*: jQuery seems to take the `duration` parameter as a delay. On click it waits, then fastly runs the animation in a not linear way. Sometimes, it starts the animation right away but still not in a linear way.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there something wrong with my browser (Chromium v.42)? It doesn't work on Firefox either. Opera seems not having any problem though.

Thanks for helping me out.

[(not so) working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjr5xbqw/4/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23575165/1654265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.progress-bar { transition: width 0.6s ease 0s; }` declaration in `bootstrap.min.css` interferes with jQuery. Remove that and it will work fine. Alternatively you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mjr5xbqw/8/) example that uses css transition:

JS

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.progress-'+id).addClass( 'progress-bar-full' );       
});
```

css

```
.progress-bar {
    transition: width 5s linear;
    width: 5%;
}
.progress-bar-full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: *Removing* it is a bit overkill. Just override it

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with how bootstrap handles transitions. Override the default behavior with your own like below.

```
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjr5xbqw/10/